# three.js Raycaster does seem to work on the basis of the first key frame of animation all the time

Tags: javascript, three.js

Raycasting selection is working fine for my project on static meshes, however for animated meshes the ray selection doesn't seem to see the movement of the mesh and only responds to the mesh's non-animated (original) position.

This is an animated model that can only pick up the pose state below the first frame and creates a small red dot when I detect the model
The bones matrices are computed by the CPU, but the new vertex positions are computed by GPU.
So the CPU has access to the first pose only.
That's why RayCasting does not work (properly) for skinned meshes.

My idea is to update the model position when updating the animation, or use GPU calculations to get the location, but I don't know how to do it. I'm looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you.

#### Static model

[image: static model]

#### Animated model

[image: animate model]

[`jsfddle view`](https://jsfiddle.net/huolala/ckduhaq7/)

Comment: Maybe the following fiddle is interesting to you (https://jsfiddle.net/fnjkeg9x/1/). I've recently developed it for the three.js forum and it shows how you calculate the current AABB for a skinned mesh. You can basically use the code in context of raycasting. But be aware that this method is very CPU intensive.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't done this project recently. I've studied your code carefully, but it doesn't seem to be suitable for me to pick up a specific material or location of the model. I want to collide with the model and add markup ,like this (https://skfb.ly/6D8MA) @Mugen87

Answer (score 1):

Currently, raycasting in three.js supports morph targets (for `THREE.Geometry` only) by replicating the vertex shader computations on the CPU.

So yes, in theory, you could add the same functionality to support raycasting for skinned meshes for both `THREE.Geometry` and `THREE.BufferGeometry`. However, a more efficient approach would be to use "GPU picking".

You can find an example of GPU picking in [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html). In the example, the objects are not animated, but the concept is the same.

three.js r.98

Comment: I'm sorry that it took so long to reply to you. I tried a lot of methods, but for this GPU example on the official website, I couldn't try to use the complex model structure, that is, I couldn't get a specific location and material of the model.I want to collide with the model and add markup ,like this (http://skfb.ly/6D8MA)

Comment: @火辣辣 Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'm trying to figure out a very similar problem. Thanks!